# Why are member variables with the same name in Child and Parent classes considered distinct? When would this be useful?

Tags: c++

Parent and Child's var are different entities. Why aren't they considered to be the same? When would be an occasion you would use the same name to refer to different things?

```
class Parent {
public:
    int var = 20;
    Parent() {}  
    void print() {cout << var << endl;}
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    int var = 4;
    Child(): Parent() {}
};

Child c{};
cout << c.var << endl; // Child's var
c.print(); // Parent's var
```

Comment: They're not considered to be the same because (a) that's how the language works, and (b) they're not the same. The one in `Parent` is its own entity, accessible via `Parent::var`. And that includes from a child instance (either via `Parent::var` within a child member function, or `c.Parent::var` from outside such as in your partial sample code. `Parent::print` has no clue of what derivations have (and shouldn't) so `var` in that member is the only `var` it knows about: `Parent::var`.

Comment: I for one think that the current behavior is more intuitive than what you're proposing. It uses the same shadowing rule as for member functions, and it makes derived classes more resilent to unexpected changes in base classes. Also, it reduces the number of edge cases (what would happen if initializers are different like in your code, or if types are different, of if access modifiers are different, etc).

Comment: If someone modifies `Parent` and not knowing about the `Child` class you implemented and chooses the same name for one of their variables as one you already use, would you rather see your program break for seemingly no reason since your variable suddenly contains a different value or not. Also would you be happy, if a customer that created the `Child` class filed a bug report mentioning that `Parent::print` no longer prints the correct value? Also: What happens, if the types are different? What happens, if the variable is private in Parent? ...